# Using createSpy in Jasmine to test module-internal setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

Within a nodejs class i have an internal function `called _timerEvent` which will be called from an setInterval.

The calls has two methods, startInterval and stopInterval where the first method calls

```
this._timerForInterval = setInterval(this._timerEvent, this._interval * 1000);
```

calling stopIntervall calls

```
clearInterval(this._timerForInterval);
```

Now i want to test with jasmine if `this._timerEvent` has been called:

```
var spyTimerEvent = null;
            controller._timerEvent = jasmine.createSpy('spyTimerEvent');
            jasmine.clock().install();

            controller.setInterval(60);
            controller.startInterval();
            expect(spyTimerEvent).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

            jasmine.Clock().tick(61);

            expect(spyTimerEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();

            jasmine.clock().uninstall();
```

I got the error: `"Expected a spy, but got null"`

I tried several approaches but i think i did not got the concept if using jasmine.clock.

Can anyone hint me on the right way?

Comment: Try to ```createSpy``` and ```install()``` in ```beforeEach```. And ```uninstall()``` in ```afterEach()``` as in ```jasmine``` [guide](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions)